# Nernst equations for the reduction of sulfate(IV) and nitrate(V) anions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, reduction-potential, nernst-equation

> Write a Nernst equation $(\pu{25 °C})$ for system:
>
> $$\ce{SO3^2- + 3 H2O + 6 e- -> S^2- + 6 OH-}\tag{R1}$$
>
> and system:
>
> $$\ce{NO3- + 3 H+ + 2 e- -> HNO2 + H2O}\tag{R2}$$

I am not really sure if these are correct:

$$
\begin{align}
E_1 &= E^\circ(\ce{SO3^2-}/\ce{S^2-}) - \frac{0.059}{6}\log\frac{[\ce{S^2-}]\cdot \left(\frac{10^{-14}}{[\ce{OH-}]}\right)^6}{[\ce{SO3^2-}]}\tag{1}\\
E_2 &= E^\circ(\ce{NO3^-}/\ce{HNO2}) - \frac{0.059}{2}\log\frac{[\ce{HNO2}]}{[\ce{NO3^-}]\cdot[\ce{H+}]^3}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

I don't know how to deal with the $\ce{OH-}$ in the equation. Am I supposed to consider $\ce{OH-}$ at all? Or should I count with it in form of $[\ce{H+}]$—in that case, can I use $K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H+}]\cdot[\ce{OH-}]$ (as written above in my solving attempt)?

Comment: See [Libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Electrochemistry/Nernst_Equation) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation). Pay more attention to the prior research before asking.

Comment: Consider the Nernst equation as a kind of a wrapper of the expression for the reaction quotient. Water in involved implicitly.

Comment: Note that $\ce{SO3^2-}$ is sulfite not sulfate. . .

Comment: @Andrew Note that the PIN for $\ce{SO3^2-}$ *is* sulfate(IV), not sulfite (*trioxidosulfate(IV)* would be even more correct). "Sulfite" might still be used more often, but, strictly speaking, it is an obsolete name. Given multiple choices, the safest option in my opinion is to follow up-to-date IUPAC nomenclature unless it is a three-lines-of-text name that can be replaced with a short abbreviation or a traditional name.

Comment: @andselisk dihydrogen monoxide == water ;)

Comment: @NilayGhosh  It may become more convenient to abandon new IUPAC names,  using just formulas.  ;-)

Comment: @Merida Why should be $\ce{OH-}$ ion  treated differently than any other ion ? And why do you use $\ce{[H+]}=\pu{e-14}/[\ce{OH-}]$ instead of $\ce{[OH-]}$  ?

Comment: @Poutnik We were always told to use expresions for [H+] rather than [OH−]. From our teachers point of view - it is more convenient/useful.

Comment: Well, it is case dependent. This is not the case. You can still do it, but **properly**. Replace [OH-] by Kw/[H+], not by [H+]=Kw/[OH-].